# How can I pass an integer to an ORACLE database?

Tags: php, oracle

I have to pass parameters as Numbers from php to ORACLE. Is there any way to do that ? Cause I need to delete the row with the ID that is given. But if I try oci_by_name I get: 
"numeric or value error: character to number conversion error ORA-06512"

Here is my code

```
<?php   
$conn = oci_connect('DBadmin', 'dbadmin', 'PETLOVERSDB');
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}    
        $deleteOption = $_GET['selectedId'];     
        $CategorySelected = $_GET['selectedOption'];

        if($CategorySelected == "Pet Type"){  
            $stid = ociparse($conn, "BEGIN  setting_package.DELETE_Type(:p1); END;");
        }  
        oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':p1', $deleteOption);
        oci_execute($stid); 
        oci_close($conn);

?>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: `intval($_GET['selectedId'])`?

Comment: You simply can't trust user input. `$_GET['selectedOption']` could hold any arbitrary string, like `Moo!`. What does it contain in your case?

Answer (score 0):

Depends what `setting_package.DELETE_Type` procedure expect. If this is a `VARCHAR2` then you could handle it inside that `PL/SQL` routine, but otherwise I would pre-check in `PHP` and only pass a number, otherwise the `PL/SQL` call will crash with I think a `ORA-01722: not a valid number` or so.